# Where are the facet blocks for search?

Tags: 8, search

In drupal 8, I have added couple of facets at this page /admin/config/search/facets

According to the documentation I should now have some blocks to put on the search page.  But I do not see any blocks that represent those facets on the Admin block page(admin/structure/block)

the block for the faceted search does not show up when I look for it in place block modal dialog.

What step am I missing?

Comment: You should mention that "the block for the faceted search does not show up when I look for it in place block modal dialog." So that people aren't mistaken.

Comment: [This Page](http://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2016/set-faceted-apache-solr-search-page-on-drupal-8-search-api-solr-and-facets) seems to suggest that you should be able to add them as normal, is it possible you've missed a different step along the line, like maybe you clicked the checkbox next to the facet and didn't save before you went in to configure it, so the block never got created?

Answer (score 1):

The block is already created; you just need to place it following these steps:

1. Go to *Structure > Block layout*
2. Click on _Place block; you will get the list of available blocks
3. Search for the facet block and click on *Place block*